# How to use variable labels in R?

Tags: r, variables, loops, character, label

I have a function that takes input as the column name of dataframe as `columnname~1`.

The dataframe consists of about 50 columns in which I want to repeat the process, I can

use a for loop to generate column name as a character which unfortunately the function does

not recognize.  The difference is just `M1~1` (works) vs `"M1"~1`

Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: autoKrige.cv(S1~1, coopyf, model = c("Sph", "Exp", "Gau"), verbose=c(TRUE, TRUE),nmax=10  In the above function variable is 1

Comment: Could you add a simple example which reproduces your problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try:

```
as.formula(paste("M1","1",sep="~"))
```

Answer (score 4):

Use the "[[ function?

```
datafrm[[M1]] ~ 1
```

That function will interpret the character value and convert it to a language value. Or you could use the `do.call` function. Best answers will be forthcoming if we have specifics of the dataframe and the function.

Answer (score 3):

Or as an alternative to paste you can use sprintf:

```
variablename = "M1"
as.formula(sprintf("%s ~ 1", variablename))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this:

```
substitute(columnname~1,list(columnname=as.name("M1")))
```

EDIT

It will also work when you substitute "M1" with variable containing string (M1 <- "M1").