# how to use variable lables in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am generating a scatter plot using ggplot2, and I would like to use the variable labels as the title of x axis and y axis. How can I do it? Thanks.

x0, y0 are function variables. Assume x0 has label "labelx", and y0 has label "labely". The code is something like this, but how do I use label as xtitle and ytitle? Thanks.

```
scatplot <- function(x0, y0){
  ggplot(data = test, aes(x = x0, y = y0)) + 
  geom_point() +
  geom_smooth(se = FALSE, method = "lm",  color = "blue", size = 1) +
  scale_x_continuous(xtitle) +
  scale_y_continuous(ytitle)
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use variable labels in R?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9268154/how-to-use-variable-labels-in-r)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The name of an object `x` passed to a function can be accessed with `deparse(substitute(x))`.

Hence, you could replace `xtitle` and `ytitle` with `deparse(substitute(x0))` and `deparse(substitute(y0))`, respectively.